# Is there a Growth discrete model for 2d-Euler eqn but non-zero vorticity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

For the $2d$ KPZ eqn:

$$h_{t}=\mu\Delta h+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla h)^{2}+\eta$$

there are various growth discrete models that converge to it; for example TASEP and lozenge tilings.

By taking the curl of

$$v=-\nabla h$$

we obtain the $2d$ Burgers eqn

$$v_{t}+v\cdot \nabla v=\mu \Delta v+\nabla \eta$$ and $\nabla \times v=0$. So $v$ is interpreted as the slope of the growth pyramids.

Any suggested analogous discrete growth models for 2d Euler:  $v_{t}+v\cdot \nabla v=\mu \Delta v+\nabla \eta$ and $\omega=\nabla \times v=-\Delta \psi$ is the vorticity.

In other words, is there a corresponding "KPZ" and discrete growth model for 2d Euler as we have for 2d Burgers?